# .htaccess url rewrite does not return entire URL

Tags: php, regex, apache

.htacess rules I've used -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [QSA,NE]
```

correct example -

```
http://mydomain.com/http://fatalweb.com/articles/8/definitions-for-htaccess-regex-character
```

the value passed to $1 is - `http://fatalweb.com/articles/8/definitions-for-htaccess-regex-character`

```
http://mydomain.com/https://www.google.com/search?q=_get&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t
```

the value passed to $1 is - `https:/www.google.com/search`

How do i make sure the entire url `https://www.google.com/search?q=_get&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t` along with all the query parameters are passed to $1

Answer (score 0):

In your question, is it `https:/www.google.com/search`? There is one slash after `https:/` is missing.

Before you are going to use the empty file handler, you need to specify at least one rule. Don't know why, but that's how it is working. Check this out for your use case:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.dummy$ ./?dummy=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./%{QUERY_STRING}
```

The line `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.dummy$ ./?dummy=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]` is dummy. Check and see if this works for you! :)